# What are the  body part damage modifiers on GOW3?

Tags: gears-of-war-3

Are there any damage modifiers on Gears of War 3, depending on what part of the body you are shooting?

I know you can get headshots with certain weapons, so there must be a damage modifier on that body part at least.

*An example; 1 shot to the head with a longshot is a kill, 1 shot to the torso with the longshot will not even down the target.*

Comment: I think you've just answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that Gears of War 3 pays attention to what body part is being shot. A shot to the head obviously does more damage with certain weapons like you said. Getting shot in the arm, leg, or chest should do the same damage with most weapons.

Besides the head, GoW 3 doesn't have specific damage modifiers to certain body parts.

On a side note, when I was searching for a chart for proof of this, I found a chart of the weapons and their damage, fire rates, and clip size. This could be useful in some way to you:

http://www.ign.com/wikis/gears-of-war-3/Weapon_Statistics_Chart